# background image change to external image link not working

Tags: css

```
<div class="flipbook-viewport">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="flipbook">
            <div style="background-image:url("https://example.com/images/lareg/1.JPG")"></div>
            <div style="background-image:url(pages/2.jpg)"></div>
            <div style="background-image:url(pages/3.jpg)"></div>
            <div style="background-image:url(pages/4.jpg)"></div>
            <div style="background-image:url(pages/5.jpg)"></div>
            <div style="background-image:url(pages/6.jpg)"></div>
            <div style="background-image:url(pages/7.jpg)"></div>
            <div style="background-image:url(pages/8.jpg)"></div>
            <div style="background-image:url(pages/9.jpg)"></div>
            <div style="background-image:url(pages/10.jpg)"></div>
            <div style="background-image:url(pages/11.jpg)"></div>
            <div style="background-image:url(pages/12.jpg)"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I change local image to external image?
I change the path to "link" but not working. Is the code wrong?

Comment: `style="background-image:url("https://example.com/images/lareg/1.JPG")"` is an invalid attribute. You can’t nest double quotes within each other. Why are you using the inner double quotes to begin with? The relative paths don’t have them, so why should the absolute URL have it? Please [validate your HTML](https://html5.validator.nu/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use single quotes for the link string

```
<div style="background-image:url('http://codeskulptor-assets.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/assets_clock_background.png')"></div>
```

Also, make sure your image is a valid link

**EDIT**

Also, also, you need height and width as mentioned my @Julius Guevarra

Answer (score -1):

You must specify a width and height for the `div`

`<div style="background-image:url(https://example.com/images/lareg/1.JPG); width: 300px; height: 300px;">`